# How to display dependency diagram for java program?

Tags: java

I want to display the dependency relationship (import) on my Java program. I know IntelliJ has diagram > show diagram feature, but it is used for "is-a" relationship, not "has-a" relationship between different class. Which tool provide dependency relationship diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you see only the **classes/interfaces** names. If you want to see more details(fields) in the diagram, go to **File > Settings... > Tools > Diagrams** and check what you want (E.g.: Fields, Methods, etc.)

[image]

Comment: What if I want to see it's parents? Eg. Class A was imported by Class B, I can check diagram from Class A?

Comment: I found there is "show dependencies" button on the diagram bar, program resolved.